# Do not want to set private to default in Java

Tags: java, default, private, access-specifier

I have this in one class:

```
if (people.count < 10)
    return false;
```

But *count* is undermarked with red saying 
*Change the visibility of count to default*

*count* is in another class as private. But I don't want to change it to default.
I know it is a bad practice.
How can I make it work without setter and getters?

Comment: why don't you want to use getters and setters?

Comment: Besides getters and setters and public fields your only other (and really bad in this case) option is reflection

Comment: *How can I make it work without setter and getters?* Simple answer: **you can't**. This looks more like a whimsey than a design issue (that's why I downvote it). You could use reflection to handle the job but is a hack alternative instead of good design and practices (maybe that's up to you)

Comment: Please post the class of the instance `people`.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone! I will use getter: people.getCount()

Comment: You could have [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) set the getters and setters for you (just add a simple @Data annotation to your class and you get them automatically for all private fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either change the visibility or expose a getter.  Asking for another way to do this is literally asking, "how can I expose a variable without exposing it?"  So, your call.

Comment: Or switch to Clojure (it doesn't treat "private" as private :)

Answer (score 1):

The field `count` is private because it's [encapsulated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) in the class. You're not intended to access it other than through a non-private member of the class.

Changing its access to 'default' would be easy but harmful.

Accessing it through a number of hacks (reflection, native methods, ...) would be more complex and still harmful.

Exposing a getter is easy and appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (people.getCount() < 10)
    return false;
```

Comment: From the question: "How can I make it work without setter and getters?"

Answer (score 0):

You only have the two choices; change the visibility or use getters and setters. The advantage of using getters and setters is that it adheres to the principle of encapsulation which in Java is important.